# Ubuntu 12.04 unlock Keyring automatically upon login in ssh session. (Other than No password on keyring))

Tags: 12.04, ssh, dbus, gnome-keyring

First I have a "login" keyring that is supposed to be unlocked upon login, it has the same login as my desktop login. Now, This works when a graphical session is used, however when I ssh into the machine, the keyring is not automatically unlocked.

I already setup all the pam_gnome_keyring config in pam login/ pam passwd but it still not working

Also, when sshing into the machine, the keyring daemon was not available. 
So I added this into my ~/.bash_profile

eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax`

How do I make keyring to be automatically unlocked upon login in ssh session.

Thanks